# How secure is TeXShop+Truecrypt on OS X?

Tags: macos, encryption, truecrypt, texshop, mactex

All of the question I would like to ask is pretty much contained in the title...

I have a couple Truecrypt-encrypted folders on OS X, where I keep some .tex documents I edit in TeXShop, and the question is: does TexShop 'bleed' information? Does it store temporary files anywhere else on the system? Filenames, filecontents etc.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20070906022746216) article, TeXShop creates temporary files when converting to PDF.

Depending on your version of Mac OS X, [you can use File Monitor](http://alphaomega.software.free.fr/filemonitor/File%20Monitor.html) to watch for changes and investigate exactly what files TeXShop creates when you use it.